# How to define the callback in Deep Learning?

Tags: callback, deep-learning, keras

Would you please guide me what the philosophy of Callbacks is? In other words, how can I define them for each unique problem?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are taking about keras. So callbacks are used to execute code during training. Everything is explained quite well [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

Here an example on how to log loss during training:

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        print logs.get('loss')

model.fit(data, data, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(data, data), verbose=0, shuffle=False,callbacks=[LossHistory()])
```